# get value from html when ajaxs returns a html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

so i have a ajax function that displays a table dynamical

```
$(#table).html(result) //result is the result returned form ajax
```

so inside my table i have a id which i want to fetch and alert, somthing like this

```
<table> 
 <tr>
   <td id="id" >123</td>
 </tr>
</tr>
```

so i did this

this happens after the complete on success in ajax

```
  success: function (result) {
           $(#table).html(result)
},
     complete: function () {
       var id= $("#id").val();
          alert(id);
}
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because .Val() returns the value.

```
<td id="id" value="123">123</td>
```

What you want to return to make your code to work is the innerHtml of the property. In Jquery you can retrieve it with this:

```
$("#id").html();
```

Comment: honest to god i am the dumbest person ever thank u so much

Comment: It happens all the time - I just did that several times today :-D